# Python: Remove List/Array tag from json Object

Tags: python, json, list

I have object like

```
{'a':['','','sample']}
```

i have deleted every blank value

```
{'a':['sample']}
```

now the problem is for just one value i dont want array, So how to remove array

**result should be**

```
{'a':'sample'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you've got `a={'a':['sample']}` and you want to get rid of the array. Supposing you know for sure that all the values are arrays. Let's do it!

```
if len(a['a']) == 1:
    a = {'a': a['a'][0]}
```

Here you're first extracting the array itself with`a['a']` and then dealing with its first member.

Here's how it looks like in the Python interpreter.

```
>>> a={'a':['sample']}
>>> a
{'a': ['sample']}
>>> a={'a':a['a'][0]}
>>> a
{'a': 'sample'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `for loop and iterating dictionary values`

**Code:**

```
sam = {'a':['sample'],'b':[1,2,3]}
for key, value in sam.items():
    if isinstance(value,list) and len(value) == 1:
        sam[key] = value[0]
print sam
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': 'sample', 'b': [1, 2, 3]}
```

**Notes:**

- The program is iterating over the `key, value` tuple
- For each value we are checking if it is a `list and length is equal to 1`
- If so we are getting the first element

Answer (score 0):

```
def reduce(arr):
    out = [ i for i in arr if i ]
    return out[0] if len(out) == 1 else out
obj = {'a':['','','sample']}
obj = {k: reduce(val) for k, val in obj.iteritems()}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mydict = {'a':['','','sample'], 'b':['','','table']}

str = ""

for key, value in mydict.items():

    for i in value:
        str += ''.join(i)

    value = ''.join(str)

    str = ""

    mydict[key] = value
```